# finding the closest to goal available cell in a grid that is not an obstacle, and is as close as possible to starting cell?

Tags: python, algorithm

I'll describe the problem: I'm trying to implement a navigation algorithm
in which I have an occupancy grid, where 0 means the cell is available and 1 means that the cell is occupied with an obstacle.
I get as input: a starting location cell, a goal location cell, and and occupancy grid (matrix), and I need to return the path from the start to goal. (I will do it with Astar)

The problem is that my goal can be on an obstacle or unreachable, while the starting cell is promised to be available. If my goal is an occupied cell I need to return the closest cell to the goal that is reachable, and if possible I want also to have it as close as possible to the starting cell, meaning if I have two cells that are both available and has minimal distance from goal I will choose the one that is the closest to my starting cell.

```
Example 1:

S 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 
0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0
0 0 T 1 G 1 A 0 
0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0
0 0 0 0 A 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

In example 1 we assume that the cell G (goal) is occupied so we need to set another goal, so in A (alternate) (and T) we have all the candidates
to be the alternative goal, but we chose cell T because it is the closest
to S in the number of steps (up, down, left and right) we should take to reach it (7 steps).

```
Example 2:

S 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 
0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 
0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0
0 T 1 0 G 0 1 A 
0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0
0 0 1 1 1 1 1 0
0 0 0 0 A 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

In example 2 we assume that G is free, but is unreachable as we can see (there is a "fence" of 1's around it) so the candidate goals will be marked with A, but we will choose again cell T, because it is also the closest to our starting cell.

I thought about this algorithm: 
1) use flood-fill to get all reachable cells. 
2) check if G is reachable. 
3) if it does, use Astar to reach it. 
4) if not, (here I have a problem to find the closest to goal that is also the closest to S) 
5) print path
Would love to hear your ideas, thanks!

Comment: please share what you have tried with a [mcve]

Comment: The [Dijkstra's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm) may help you. You can store somehow the distance from a cell to the goal cell, for the case it's unreachable and get the minimum.

Comment: Voting to close as too broad as this is essentially asking us to either solve the entire exercise for you or teach you graph theory. If you can narrow down the question to a specific enough sub-step, it might be more answerable.

Comment: I know graph theory very well, And I'm not seeking a solution, just an idea.
I thought about this algorithm:
1) use flood-fill to get all reachable cells.
2) check if G is reachable.
3) if it does, use Astar to reach it.
4) if not, (here I have a problem to find the closest to goal that is also the closest to S)
5) print path

Comment: @elihar: please edit this thinking into you posting: it's a critical part of your question.

Comment: OK. Doing it now.

Answer (score 1):

You're very close with your flood-fill algorithm.  Instead of merely flood-filling, use your graph algorithms to find the distance to each reachable square.

If you reach the goal square, you're done, with a distance and route readily available.
Other wise ...

Use the same algorithm from the goal block -- but now you get to ignore obstacles.  Continue until you hit a set of cells reachable from the start (i.e. any cells in the set are at the same, minimal distance from `G`).  Check which of these cells has the least distance to `S` (from your first step).

---

I'm suggesting a layered flood-fill which draws on the crux of Dijkstra.
Your start cell is 0.  Now mark every adjacent open cell with a 1.  Next, go through your `1` cells; mark every open adjacent cell with `2`.  Continue this until you (a) run out of open cells, or (b) hit a goal cell.

Comment: Can you please elaborate more, What you mean by "use your graph algorithms to find the distance"?

Comment: Dijkstra's algorithm + flood-fill gives you the distance to every reachable cell.

Comment: I will think about what you say, but I got to admit it is not immediate for me, unfortunately.
Thanks a lot!

Comment: You said "I know graph theory very well".  Your cells form a graph with the connectivity defined by single-step moves; each edge has a cost of 1.  Dijkstra's algorithm will give you the shortest distance to every reachable cell.  A breadth-first flood-fill will also do this, giving each cell the value of the layer on which it's filled.  That should get you moving.

Comment: So if I understood correctly you are suggesting that I will run flood fill, then mark each cell that is not marked with infinity weight, else the weight will be 1.
Then run dijkstra, and if one path is available - I'm done. else, if more than one minimum path is available, I'll run dijkstra again from the start position and then I'm done.
Am I correct?